# How can I get pkg-config to work within eclipse juno (Mac OS X)?

Tags: eclipse, macos, gtkmm, pkg-config

I try to get gtkmm running within eclipse. This is my makefile (without the cleaning):

```
all : main.cpp
@export PATH+=/opt/local/bin;
@echo PATH=$(PATH);

g++ -v `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags` \
    -O0 -g3 -Wall -S \
    -o main.o main.cpp;
g++ -v -o main.exe main.o \
    `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 \
    --libs` ;
```

In the Console I get (amongst other output):

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
g++ -v `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags` \
    -O0 -g3 -Wall -S \
    -o main.o main.cpp;
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
```

I did:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/pkg-config /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
```

And when I type

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config
```

in Terminal, I get:

```
Must specify package names on the command line
```

So I assume pkg-config works in the "Terminal" ... But not in eclipse.

What can I do?
Thanks!
Nils

Comment: Ok, adding the output of `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags` and `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --lib` manually instead got me rid of that error.. still, it seems like.. no.. dont do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what solved my Problem, since now, it works.
I guess it was one of the following:

- makefile now looks like this:

  ```
  all: main.cpp
      g++ -v `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags`-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -o main.o main.cpp;
      g++ -v -o main.exe main.o `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs`
  clean:
      rm -f main.exe main.o
  ```
- I have smybolic link towards pkg-config within /bin:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/pkg-config /bin/pkg-config
  ```
- I installed XQuartz
- I updated MacPorts and all outdated ports:

  ```
  sudo port -v selfupdate
  sudo port upgrade outdated
  ```